# Getting 404 error on pages opened before any deployment on vercel server for nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, http-status-code-404, vercel

If a tab has been opened with the website and a new code has been deployed to the production. As soon as we click on any link or navigate to a new page in the tab previously opened 404 page is triggered. But reloading the page fixes the issue.

**My findings-**

- Before the deployment the page data is fetched from next server through call of https://www.example.com/_next/data/fK9hQ6OYXQsFaKRCCUnoj/properties.json
- After the deployment of new code the part next to /data changes. https://www.example.com/_next/data/HCwieH8i6BCYUaYYC7m_K/properties.json

But the tab previously opened tries to fetch data from the old url an hence encounters 404 error.

If you need any more info please let me know.

Please help me out with this. This issue has been bugging me since a long time.

Comment: It's probably caused by a cache

Comment: Any suggestions how i can solve it? Nextjs should inherently take care of this.

Comment: How long do you have to wait to make the website works as intended?

Comment: Until the page is refreshed. As much as i know nextjs should automatically detect a new version. But not doing so in my case

Comment: How would the client-side app detect a change in the Next.js server without making a new request to it? The previous version of the pages gets cached due to prefetching done by Next.js when that page gets first loaded. You can either try to prevent the prefetching from occurring to avoid the caching, OR force a page refresh programmatically to update the cached version.

Comment: I believe that it can be caused by your browser's cache